# Ignore lines in CSV file c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have an issue with a CSV file. I want to skip the first couple of lines that are not relevant at this point and start processing the file from where the actual data comes in. Is there a way of skipping all the headers?

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace bike
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var col1 = new List<string>();
            var col2 = new List<string>();
            var col3 = new List<string>();
            var col4 = new List<string>();

            var Column1 = col1.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
            var Column2 = col2.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
            var Column3 = col3.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));
            var Column4 = col4.Select<string, int>(q => Convert.ToInt32(q));



            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Heart Rate");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "Speed");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col3", "Power");
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("col4", "Altitude");



            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                {

                    int row = 0;
                    string line;

                    bool isInHRData = false;

                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
                    {
                        if (!isInHRData)
                        {
                            if (line != "[HRData]")
                                continue;
                            isInHRData = true;
                            continue;
                        }

                        else if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("["))
                            break;

                        string[] columns = line.Split('\t');
                        if (columns.Length > 0)
                            col1.Add(columns[0]);
                        if (columns.Length > 1)
                            col2.Add(columns[1]);
                        if (columns.Length > 2)
                            col3.Add(columns[2]);
                        if (columns.Length > 3)
                            col4.Add(columns[3]);



                        /*col1.Add(columns[0]);
                        col2.Add(columns[1]);
                        col3.Add(columns[2]);
                        col4.Add(columns[3]);
                         */

                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
                        {
                            dataGridView1[i, row].Value = columns[i];
                        }
                        row++; 
                    }

                    int maxSpeed = Column2.Max();
                    maxSpeed = maxSpeed / 10;
                    string MaxSpeed = Convert.ToString(maxSpeed);
                    textBox1.Text = MaxSpeed;

                    double aveSpeed = Column2.Average();
                    aveSpeed = aveSpeed / 10;
                    aveSpeed = Math.Round(aveSpeed, 0);
                    string AveSpeed = Convert.ToString(aveSpeed);
                    textBox2.Text = AveSpeed;

                    double aveHeart = Column1.Average();
                    aveHeart = Math.Round(aveHeart, 0);
                    string AveHeart = Convert.ToString(aveHeart);
                    textBox3.Text = AveHeart;

                    int maxHeart = Column1.Max();
                    string MaxHeart = Convert.ToString(maxHeart);
                    textBox4.Text = MaxHeart;

                    int minHeart = Column1.Min();
                    string MinHeart = Convert.ToString(minHeart);
                    textBox5.Text = MinHeart;

                    double avePower = Column3.Average();
                    avePower = Math.Round(avePower, 0);
                    string AvePower = Convert.ToString(avePower);
                    textBox6.Text = AvePower;

                    int maxPower = Column3.Max();
                    string MaxPower = Convert.ToString(maxPower);
                    textBox7.Text = MaxPower;

                    double aveAltitude = Column4.Average();
                    aveAltitude = Math.Round(aveAltitude, 0);
                    string AveAltitude = Convert.ToString(aveAltitude);
                    textBox8.Text = AveAltitude;

                    int maxAltitude = Column4.Max();
                    string MaxAltitude = Convert.ToString(maxAltitude);
                    textBox9.Text = MaxAltitude;


                }
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And example of a CSV file (HRData bit is the only one I need to display so I want to ignore all the rest):

```
[Params]
Version=106
Monitor=34
SMode=111000100
Date=20101110
StartTime=13:47:00.0
Length=02:07:41.7
Interval=5
Upper1=150
Lower1=140
Upper2=0
Lower2=0
Upper3=180
Lower3=177
Timer1=00:00:00.0
Timer2=00:00:00.0
Timer3=00:00:00.0
ActiveLimit=0
MaxHR=195
RestHR=48
StartDelay=0
VO2max=54
Weight=0

[Note]

[IntTimes]
00:01:23.7  139 0   118 139
0   0   0   290 75  69
0   0   0   0   0
0   444 0   70  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
00:30:51.4  157 0   145 158
0   0   0   372 133 2
0   0   0   0   0
0   16020   0   90  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
01:04:46.0  148 0   146 157
0   0   0   245 118 11
0   0   0   0   0
0   32000   0   80  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
01:34:33.7  138 0   144 152
0   0   0   336 116 32
0   0   0   0   0
0   46524   0   70  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
02:06:40.4  145 0   144 160
0   0   0   253 130 60
0   0   0   0   0
0   60432   0   60  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0
02:07:41.7  119 0   129 145
0   0   0   0   75  55
0   0   0   0   0
0   60791   0   60  0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0

[IntNotes]
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6   

[ExtraData]

[LapNames]
1   0   
2   0   
3   0   
4   0   
5   0   
6   0   

[Summary-123]
7660    0   820 5995    845 0
195 150 140 48
7660    0   820 5995    845 0
195 0   0   48
0   0   0   0   0   0
195 0   0   48
0   1532

[Summary-TH]
7660    0   7660    0   0   0
195 0   0   48
0   1532

[HRZones]
195
176
156
137
117
98
0
0
0
0
0

[SwapTimes]

[Trip]
607
329
7661
15
70
286
494
4720

[HRData]
91  161 0   64
91  159 0   64
98  225 56  63
105 260 68  63
106 183 70  63
101 52  55  63
104 119 29  63
110 153 32  63
118 161 42  64
124 113 43  65
123 77  38  66
125 189 32  66
129 248 64  66
134 272 73  66
137 271 75  67
137 270 73  67
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
...
int row = 0;
string line;
bool isInHRData = false;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
    if (!inHRData)
    {
         if (line == "[HRData]")
              isInHRData = true;
         continue;
    } 
    ....
```

If there is another section AFTER `HRData`, add the following code:

```
...
int row = 0;
string line;
bool isInHRData = false;

while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
{
    if (!inHRData)
    {
         if (line == "[HRData]")
              isInHRData = true;
         continue;
    } 
    else if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("[")) // This criteria can be mucht better, checking for words, etc. but you in essence this will work.
        break;
    ....
```

For the IndexOutOfRangeException:

```
string[] columns = line.Split('\t');
if (columns.Length > 0)
     col1.Add(columns[0]);
if (columns.Length > 1)
     col2.Add(columns[1]);
if (columns.Length > 2)
     col3.Add(columns[2]);
if (columns.Length > 3)
     col4.Add(columns[3]);
```

Comment: Tried it and didn't work. Comes up with IndexOutOfRangeException on line col2.Add(columns[1]);

Comment: `isInHRData = true; continue;` one more continue to also skip the `[HRData]` line. And also `... line.EndsWith("]"))`

Comment: Thank you very much guys it worked with that second continue :)

Comment: @userXXX: I updated my answer with the suggestion of Corak. In my very first answer was also a little error: `if (inHRData)` change to `if (!inHRData)`.

Comment: Also I've got another problem. It crashes when not all 4 rows of data is available. I've got many different csv files and some of them have some rows missing

Comment: Do you realy mean rows or do you mean columns (the values on one row)?

Comment: yes, sorry I meant the whole columns, as in having 3 instead of 4 etc.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? And at what line of code do you get it? Perhapse open a new question?

Comment: Another suggestion: Move everything after `row++` outside the while loop!

Comment: it's again IndexOutOfRangeException on line col2.Add(columns[1]); I've tried your suggestion with moving it out of the while loop but that didn't help.

Comment: check `columns.Length` before accessing. `col1.Add(columns.Length > 0 ? columns[0] : null); col2.Add(columns.Length > 1 ? columns[1] : null);` and so on.

Comment: @MartinMulder - that way the lists will get out of sync!

Comment: @Corak: Correct, but since he does calculation on each seperate column, they do not have to be in sync.

Comment: @MartinMulder Tried your suggestion, now it comes up with InvalidOperationException on line int maxSpeed = Column2.Max();

Comment: That means that your are trying to calculate the max. value of a column that is empty. One extra reason to move your "statistics" out of the while loop. Further more you should check for empty lists at the end.

Comment: i've already tried it with my stats out of the loop. I've updated the code to my current one in the main question.

Comment: Also I've tried commenting out all my stats and it worked. What should I do now, put them in another loop or some sort of if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the other little bugs that came out of the rest of the code I offered you to refactor. This example is no refactoring, it is totally rewritten. I seperated the logic from the user interface. This is always a good thing. It prepares you to migrate your logic to other type of applications like a web-application of WPF.

This code is totally based on seperation of responsibilities:

- HRData: The entity, the main player of your code. Your basic data. An entity is better than an int-array, because the properties give much more meaning.
- HRDataExtensions: The statistical methods, responsible for doing calculations.
- HRDataReader: Responsible for reading a file and read it into a list of HRData.

With this list of HRData, you can populate your UI-form.

```
public class HRData
{
    public int? HeartRate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int? Speed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int? Power
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int? Altitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Heart rate={0}, Speed={1}, Power={2}, Altitude={3}", HeartRate, Speed, Power, Altitude);
    }
}

public static class HRDataExtensions
{
    static private int? CalculateInt32(this IEnumerable<HRData> data, Func<HRData, int?> valueSelector, Func<IEnumerable<int?>, int?> aggregation)
    {
        List<int?> list = new List<int?>();
        list.AddRange(data.Select(valueSelector));
        return aggregation(list);
    }

    static private int? CalculateDouble(this IEnumerable<HRData> data, Func<HRData, int?> valueSelector, Func<IEnumerable<int?>, double?> aggregation)
    {
        List<int?> list = new List<int?>();
        list.AddRange(data.Select(valueSelector));
        double? result = aggregation(list);
        return (result == null) ? null : (int?)Math.Round(result.Value);
    }

    static public int? MinimumHeartRate(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.HeartRate, Enumerable.Min);
    }

    static public int? MaximumHeartRate(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.HeartRate, Enumerable.Max);
    }

    static public int? AverageHeartRate(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateDouble(hr => hr.HeartRate, Enumerable.Average);
    }

    static public int? MinimumSpeed(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.Speed, Enumerable.Min);
    }

    static public int? MaximumSpeed(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.Speed, Enumerable.Max);
    }

    static public int? AverageSpeed(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateDouble(hr => hr.Speed, Enumerable.Average);
    }

    static public int? MinimumPower(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.Power, Enumerable.Min);
    }

    static public int? MaximumPower(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.Power, Enumerable.Max);
    }

    static public int? AveragePower(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateDouble(hr => hr.Power, Enumerable.Average);
    }

    static public int? MinimumAltitude(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.Altitude, Enumerable.Min);
    }

    static public int? MaximumAltitude(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateInt32(hr => hr.Altitude, Enumerable.Max);
    }

    static public int? AverageAltitude(this IEnumerable<HRData> data)
    {
        return data.CalculateDouble(hr => hr.Altitude, Enumerable.Average);
    }
}

public static class HRDataReader
{
    static private int? ConvertValue(string[] values, int index)
    {
        if (index >= values.Length)
            return null;
        int value;
        if (int.TryParse(values[index], out value))
            return value;
        return null;
    }

    static public IList<HRData> Read(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string line;

            // First: Skip to the correct section.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                if (line == "[HRData]")
                    break;

            // Now: Read the HRData
            List<HRData> data = new List<HRData>();
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
                    break;
                line = line.Trim().Replace("\t", " "); // Remove all tabs.
                while (line.Contains("  ")) // Remove all duplicate spaces.
                    line = line.Replace("  ", " ");
                string[] values = line.Split(' '); // Split the line up.
                data.Add(new HRData
                {
                    HeartRate = ConvertValue(values, 0),
                    Speed = ConvertValue(values, 1),
                    Power = ConvertValue(values, 2),
                    Altitude = ConvertValue(values, 3)
                });
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Now you can adjust your code like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();

            IList<HRData> data = HRDataReader.Read(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "HeartRate", HeaderText = "Heart rate", DataPropertyName = "HeartRate" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Speed", HeaderText = "Speed", DataPropertyName = "Speed" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Power", HeaderText = "Power", DataPropertyName = "Power" });
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn { Name = "Altitude", HeaderText = "Altitude", DataPropertyName = "Altitude" });

            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;

            label1.Text = data.MaximumAltitude().ToString();

            textBox1.Text = data.MaximumSpeed().ToString();
            textBox2.Text = data.AverageSpeed().ToString();
            textBox3.Text = data.AverageHeartRate().ToString();
            textBox4.Text = data.MaximumHeartRate().ToString();
            textBox5.Text = data.MinimumHeartRate().ToString();
            textBox6.Text = data.AveragePower().ToString();
            textBox7.Text = data.MaximumPower().ToString();
            textBox8.Text = data.AverageAltitude().ToString();
            textBox9.Text = data.MaximumAltitude().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the code and I am struggling a bit. Never really done it like that by separating it. Do I have to call them to be able to display it in the table?

Comment: Aks your questions, that is what is site is for.

Comment: I'm guessing it is a object orientated way of doing it. Do I have to link and call them classes under my namespace?

Comment: Yes... it is a bit OOP, just a bit. Because of this it is easier to modify your own software when things change. Suppose your textfile changes into a real CSV-file (with comma's), than you only have to change the HRDataReader. The rest stays exactly the same.